# XACML: how to find a long in a list of longs (list contains)

Tags: authorization, xacml, abac, xacml3, alfa

I'm trying to do a check in a XACML policy. I have a long in my subject (urn:ch:xxxx:attribute:subject:1.0:**participantid**) context which i wish to find in a list of longs (urn:ch:xxxx:attribute:resource:1.0:**participantids**) in my resource context. I'm trying to do that with the function *integer-is-in*.

I've tried so far:

```
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:integer-is-in">
  <SubjectAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:ch:xxxx:attribute:subject:1.0:participantid" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#long" />
  <ResourceAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:ch:xxxx:attribute:resource:1.0:participantids" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#long" />
</Apply>
```

I've tested this and it worked well.

```
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:integer-is-in">
  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#long">9000501</AttributeValue>
  <ResourceAttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:ch:xxxx:attribute:resource:1.0:participantids" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#long" />
</Apply>
```

So how should I pass the subject attribute so that it works? Or is the function *integer-is-in* the wrong way?

Regards

Cristiano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An AttributeDesignator is considered a **bag** in XACML, in other words it is *multi-valued*. So you have to apply the *integer-one-and-only* function on it before you apply *integer-is-in*, because integer-is-in expects a single value (like an AttributeValue) as first argument.

Besides, *integer-is-in* and *integer-one-and-only* functions work only with the *integer* datatype (from XML schema) in the XACML standard, not *long*. So the fact that your second example *works well* tells me your XACML implementation is not 100% XACML-compliant.

Last, you are using XACML 2.0 syntax here, and I strongly recommend to upgrade to XACML 3.0 which [fixes and enhances XACML](https://wiki.oasis-open.org/xacml/DifferencesBetweenXACML2.0AndXACML3.0) in general. In XACML 3.0, the fix would look like this:

```
<Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:integer-is-in">
    <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:integer-one-and-only">
        <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:ch:xxxx:attribute:subject:1.0:participantid" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer" MustBePresent="false" />
    </Apply>
    <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:ch:xxxx:attribute:resource:1.0:participantids" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#integer" MustBePresent="false" />
</Apply>
```

Comment: Hi Cyril. Thx so much for this explanation. It helps me to solve my problem. I'll consider migrating to XACM 3.0. We've a lot of this policies working on our system and the migration will have a big impact for a lot of services. Do you know if it's a way to migrate the policies automatically? Do you know any application, that could do the job for me?

Comment: Yes, you can easily migrate from XACML 2.0 to XACML 3.0 either using XSLT or JAXB (in Java) or other means

Comment: https://www.webfarmr.eu/2015/02/use-jaxb-and-ant-to-generate-java-pojos-for-xacml-1-1-xacml-2-0-and-xacml-3-0-policies/

Comment: Yep, you can find an [XSLT stylesheet for XACML-2.0-to-3.0 policy conversion on the xacml-comment mailing list](https://lists.oasis-open.org/archives/xacml-comment/201506/msg00000.html). It works fine with Saxon XSLT processor at least, but you are free to try with other processors... at your own risk ;-)